# Fragment replaces entire screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, layout, fragment

I have the following structures and fragment replace/add does not only replace its host view but whole screen. What can cause this?

Main Activity layout without data

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_button"
        app:onNavigationItemSelected="@{viewModel::onNavigationItemSelected}"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:context=".fragment.HomeFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_button"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::onFloatingButtonClicked}"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Main activity onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new ViewModelFactory(getApplication())).get(MainViewModel.class);
    activityMainBinding.setViewModel(mainViewModel);
    activityMainBinding.executePendingBindings();

    fragmentList.put(FragmentsEnum.HOME.getValue(), new HomeFragment());
    fragmentList.put(FragmentsEnum.PROFILE.getValue(), new ProfileFragment());

    Fragments.addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragmentList.get(FragmentsEnum.HOME.getValue()), FragmentsEnum.HOME.getValue()); // DEFAULT FRAGMENT
}
```

Fragments util

```
public static void addFragment(FragmentManager manager, int containerId, Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    if (!manager.isStateSaved()) {
        manager.beginTransaction().add(containerId, fragment, tag).commit();
    }
}
```

On onview of main activity I am setting Home Fragment active when the activity starts. But it hides my bottom nav bar and replaces entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a problem with the usage of LinearLayout as the root element for the fragment and bottomnav. Try replacing it with either ConstraintLayout or CoordinatorLayout. If none of those work try removing the top padding from the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Your FrameLayout will just overlap the BottomNavigationView. Furthermore you should use the FragmentContainerView for your nav host. You'd want to have your FragmentContainerView explicitly above your BottomNavigationView. I changed your LinearLayout to a ConstraintLayout with proper constraints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
    app:defaultNavHost="true" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_button"
    app:onNavigationItemSelected="@{viewModel::onNavigationItemSelected}"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```